# Mac Office 2011 and json parsing in vba?

Tags: json, macos, vba, ms-office

all the json libraties I could find for VBA required the dictionary object which is part of the microsoft scripting runtime, which are not available on the mac. Is there a json parser working for Mac Office 2011 VBA?

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/vba-json has a json parser in pure VBA, and it seems to work fine, although I seem to recall having to make some minor modifications to get it working on all the JSON I was throwing at it. I also implemented a vba-coded Dictionary object to remove the dependency on the Scripting dictionary. You can find the one I used at http://www.sysmod.com/Dictionary.cls. Using both of these, I was able to get it working on OSX Office 2011, e.g.:

```
dim js
json_string = ...
Set jsp = New json
Set js = jsp.parse(sjson) 'sets js e.g. to a Dictionary or Collection object if json_string is "{...}" or "[...]"
```

Let me know if you need more detail to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a long time ago and I did not have a reference to the MS Scripting Runtime in the project. I used microsoft JScript and grabbed objects from it to parse the data. I dug out a thread from 2008 where a few people are talking about the same thing:

[Yahoo message thread](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/json/message/972)

It at least gives you a starting point. I've since lost that code where I did it myself. If your still stuck later give me a holler, maybe I can help some more